# Can we estimate effective population size from DNA sequence data (CR or cytB sequence)?

Tags: population-genetics

I have DNA sequence data (control region) of two population of a species. Can anybody suggest me any software to calculate effective population size? Is it possible and meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible.

**Very simple model**

It is often hard to decompose the effective population size $Ne$ from the mutation rate $\mu$ though. But it is quite common to estimate $N\mu$. For example, it is a classical result from coalescent theory assuming a single panmictic population of constant size and no selection (and a few other assumptions) that

$$N\mu = \frac{S}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{i}}$$

, where $S$ is the number of segregating sites and $k$ is the number of sampled individuals.

**More advanced models**

You will probably want a slightly more advance model though.

There exist a number of estimators including Colony2, CoNe, Estim, MLNe, ONeSAMP, TMVP and LDNe. I recommend having a look at [Gilbert and Whitlock (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kimberly_Gilbert2/publication/279458248_Evaluating_methods_for_estimating_local_effective_population_size_with_and_without_migration/links/5717caeb08aed8a339e5aeff.pdf) who compares these estimators under different demographic scenario.

Comment: Thanks, Remi. Request you to suggest some papers estimating Ne using mitochondrial DNA sequence.